# How to access a file in the dll's folder instead of the executable?

Tags: c#, dll

I have an executable that's using a dll (they're in 2 different folders).
When I do `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` in one of the methods in the dll, I'm getting the executable folder. Is there anyway to get the dll folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` to get the full path to the DLL.